# Как добавить иконку в форму?

Tags: php, ajax, input

Добрый день,у меня есть форма регистрации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все работает,теперь мне нужно сделать проверку на правильность/доступность логина/пароля через Ajax.Примерно вот так(Paint):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот,возможно ли вообще внедрить в форму Input такие вот значки,и как сделать проверку по ajax?

Comment: `возможно ли вообще внедрить в форму Input такие вот значки` - Можно! Учите верстку. `как сделать проверку по ajax?` - так же, как и остальной аякс. Берешь данные, отсылаешь, на сервере проверяешь. ответ отправляешь обратно на форму

Comment: @АлексейШиманский,Как это реализовать?Направьте пожалуйста новичка.Буду благодарен примеру

Comment: @Ersultan, доступность пароля - супер! Теперь можно подбирать пароль очень удобно :)

Comment: @Visman это форма регистрации. Полагаю там проверка на ненужные символы будет)

Comment: @Visman, там будут критерии для пароля.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иконки обычно вставляются следующим образом:

input помещается в div
инпуту делаются: прозрачный фон, отсутствие границы и прочие вещи, который отображаются
а диву мы ставим все такие же параметры как были у самого инпута
ну и соответственно, в сам div вместе с input ставим все что нужно кроме этого, в данном случае картинку

еще есть способ для input прописать стили с отображением картинки фоном

А для проверки правильности введенных данных вешаем событие на изменение содержимого и через это http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ отправляем на сервер для проверки

вот как то так